# "systemctl set-default graphical.target" does not work!

Tags: linux, gnome, desktop-environment

Could anyone help? How to set login graphical interface by default, thank you！These are what I did:

1. Redhat7, login root account, I uninstall gnome desktop `yum remove gnome-desktop3.x86_64`
2. Then I install gnome desktop `yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"`
3. Then I set `systemctl set-default graphical.target`
4. When I `reboot`, I'm back at the command line interface
5. I check `runlevel`, result `N 5`
6. When I use `startx`, successfuly enter graphical interface

Comment: Inspect `/var/log/messages` to see what happens at boot. Is your gdm, lightdm,... installed and working properly? Try also `journalctl` to see if systemd reports any problems.

Comment: @nobody thank you for your reply, now I install gdm `yum install gdm.x86_64`, but still go to command line interface, then I use `gdm`, graphic interface shows, it looks correct but there is no user/password input box...
Do I need to config gdm?

Comment: What do the following commands say: `systemctl status gdm`, `journalctl -u gdm`?

Comment: @nobody thank you!
`* gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: inactive (dead)` 
And `journalctl -u gdm` results`-- No entries --`

Comment: @nobody thank you! probelm solved `systemctl enable gdm.service`

Comment: I am glad to be able to help.